# Installing Ubuntu 18.04 alongside Windows 10 failed - boots straight into Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 18.04

I am  trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot with windows 10

I burned the iso file on DVD

I started to boot from the DVD but I see a quick message that something is not found. I can't read the message because of its speed.

While the installation happened :

```
copying files...
installing...
removing...

installing succeed.
```

I then restarted the computer and waited for the GRUB menu to appear,
but Windows 10 booted instead.

I tried selecting **Try Ubuntu without installing**, and using `mount` and `boot-repair`, but nothing happened.

Comment: Is it one of those HP BIOSes that boot straight to Windows if it's listed in the UEFI boot partition?

Comment: Can you boot grub if you select it directly (hit some key: function, esc,del,...(varies by machine) at power up and get the select boot device/os.  Select grub. What happens?

Answer (score 0):

Run this on Windows 10's cmd.exe as Administrator:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

That one line fixed my problem, hope this helps.
Credit goes to [itsFOSS.com](https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar problem. 
You may consider reading this article http://myviewsonfoss.blogspot.in/2018/05/how-to-fix-grub.html
Thanks!